# How to modify or display JSON object using jquery and mvc Model

Tags: jquery, json, asp.net-mvc-4

```
var dataToSend = '@Html.Raw(Json.Encode(Model.PageInput))';
```

my `dataToSend` contains below data :

```
"{"id":"1","name":"stackoverflow","count":25}"
```

How can I access the data?

I've tried the following :

```
alert(dataToSend.id)
```

or

```
alert(dataToSend[0].id)
```

or

```
alert(dataToSend[1].id)
```

**All outputs**: `undefined`

doesn't working. But why?!!!

Comment: "{"id":"1","name":"stackoverflow","count":25}" it is not in the correct format , The count should be "count":"25".

Answer (score 2, accepted):

replace:

```
var dataToSend = '@Html.Raw(Json.Encode(Model.PageInput))';
```

with:

```
var dataToSend = @Html.Raw(Json.Encode(Model.PageInput));
```

(it should be an `object`, not a `string`)

and then try:

```
dataToSend.name
```

P.S:

you can also parse strings into json with javascript.

string > json:

```
var obj = JSON.parse(str);
```

json > string:

```
var str = JSON.stringify(obj);
```

hope that helps.

Answer (score 1):

your `dataToSend` is a string, therefore it wont be availible,

you could try

```
var dataToSend = @Html.Raw(Json.Encode(Model.PageInput));
```

as the result will be rendered as JSON before it gets to the client.

or you could use the JSON library and do

```
var dataToSend = JSON.parse('@Html.Raw(Json.Encode(Model.PageInput))');
```